# Book about magic less world a boy who still has magic in him

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Looking for a book about a boy who finds out he has magic in him. I must have read it some time between 2007-2010. Starts off with his home being destroyed by not so nice people, he escapes and meets a thief.

They then meet a “witch” who sees the boy has magic in him. They make it a mission to restore magic to the world. There is a huge battle and there are machines that were brought back with magic.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Restoring magic to the world is a massive fantasy trope; https://bangbangbookblog.com/2017/12/11/children-of-blood-and-bone-spoilers/ or https://www.amazon.co.uk/Gifted-Thief-Highland-Magic-Harper/dp/1515903001/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8 or https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18295806-reign-of-ash, etc